# Theme for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, package-management, themes

Is there any package available for Ubuntu 14.04 where the theme will change automatically on daily basis? Also which package is good for themes with nice HD images, can you suggest one?

Comment: Is there a package like that available ? Well, no, at least not to the best of my knowledge.  Can it be scripted ? Sure can, might even post a solution at some point. `Also which package is good for themes with nice HD images` That's a separate question, buddy. One question per post, alright ? It's not a forum , but Q&A site after all

Answer (score 1):

You can download themes from [here](http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xsortmode=high&page=0&xcontentmode=167).

Installing `unity-tweak-tool` from Ubuntu software center allows you to change themes.

Comment: does this change the theme automatically on daily basis? @vishnu

Comment: @Madhusudhan It doesn't change on a daily basis.